# YouTube video playing after closing the overlay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, overlay

I am using below script for opening the overlay but when i close the overlay the iframe video is still playing in background.

HTML

```
<div class="review">
               <img onclick="show('popup')" src="images/AIRism_review-1.jpg" style="cursor: pointer;">
               <img onclick="show('popup1')" src="images/AIRism_review-2.jpg" style="cursor: pointer;">
           </div>

       <div id="popup" class="overlay">
          <div class="overlay-inner">
            <span onclick="hide('popup')" id="close">&times;</span> 
              <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xPfgku83XZk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>



<script>
    $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    var show = function(id) {
        $(id).style.display ='block';
    }
    var hide = function(id) {
        $(id).style.display ='none';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As its not clear that how you are using youtube video in your code, I am assuming you are suing the most used way, which is by embed iframe.
So
There is many ways to do it, best is to use stopVideo(); function from youtube player API.

if you have youtube player object in your code,
something like this

```
player = new YT.Player();
```

just use this function on your close button click.

```
player.stopVideo();
```

or you can do this

```
$('#parentSelectorOfYourIframe').children('iframe').attr('src', '');
```

try to go through once to youtube official player [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

after your question update, I have created this [codePen](https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/XWmaQGm) for you.

I hope this is exactly what you need, if need something else, please let me know.

Points to keep in mind..

1. add this vpaframeter in your youtube video link as I did  `?version=3&enablejsapi=1` and then you can play around with your YT player.

Comment: I have updated the answer now, check the codepen link

Comment: Actually i have 4 images and every images has the different video in there overlays from the way you provided none of the overlay is working except the one which has the id same as called in JS. So how can i do the same for all of the 4 overlays?

Comment: No... In this case don't use id.. add a class and use class by query selector and fire events only in relation to close button.

Comment: can you please create a example?

Comment: I can neeraj.. but don't you think you should try yourself.?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is that you **hide** the frame and not destroy it.
inspect your page and you'll see that the frame always exist and is juste in

```
display:"none"
```

I have tried to replace

```
$(id).style.display ='none';
```

by

```
$(id).innerHTML  = "";
```

but you don't have your frame anymore

or you can do that to

```
$(id).innerHTML  = '<div class="overlay-inner" style="display:none;"><span onclick="hide(\'popup\')" id="close">&times;</span><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xPfgku83XZk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
```

=>you replace your frame with herself but with display:none in it